# Looking for a solution where 'autofocus' attribute is working for an already loaded form (i.e. cached form)

Tags: html, angular, caching, autofocus

We are aware that the **autofocus**-attribute works only on **Page Load** & **Reload Page**.
Use-case:

1. I have 2-input fields in a form and the first input field has the **autofocus**-attribute and when the form initially loads the field has the focus [expected behavior].
2. Now, I click on the second input field and simply close this form.
3. I launch the form again (cached form comes up) - the focus persists on the second field - I want a workaround/solution where the focus remains in the first field even for a cached form in html.

A sample code

```
<input type="text" #myInput id="first" autofocus>
<input type="text" id="second" >
```

Is there a workaround for cached form to bring focus to the first input element every time?

I have tried the .focus() on the element under ngAfterViewInit() alongside have tried explicitly called the method right after the first input field (which would only work if there is only one input field in a form, because the focus doesn't move to the other field), (i.e.)
`<input type=text" #myInput id="first> {{ myInput.focus() }}`

Comment: Could you prodivde a stackblitz example of your code. I do not think that your problem is a cache problem. As far as i know angular does not cache a view by default.

Comment: @MehyarSawas, consider a button which launches a form with 2 input fields. Now the first time I launch the form, the first input field is already having the focus.
I do nothing but simply click on the other input or anywhere in the form( to remove the focus from the first input field ) and close the form.
Further, when I click on the button that launches the form yet again holds the last focus position (i.e. if I had clicked on the second input field before closing the form - the focus would still remain on the second input field on relaunching).

Comment: Still missing how you are launching and closing your form. There are many ways to do that and each way may require a different solution. If you just provide the whole code you have or a stackblitz example, you may get a suggested solution faster.